# MPNS URI timeout

Tags: windows-phone-7, push

I am using the `Microsoft Push Notification Service` to send push notifications, and i am using the unique device id as the channel name to insure a unique URI for the application. 
`byte[] myDeviceID=(byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
            string channelName = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID);`
The **problem** is that when i don't access the URI for sometime (hours), i get a new URI for the same channel name and this causes big problems.

So **is there a timeout for the URI** and if so what is it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sometimes the Channel URI is updated. Therefore, you need to properly handle [HttpNotificationChannel.ChannelUriUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.channeluriupdated%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Whenever an application is running, there is no guarantee that the single opened URI will be persistent.

Comment: I am using the event handler so when i get the URI, i subscribe to the service at server and then to notifications.  But can you clarify on how this works if the URI changed.  Does the MPNS send back to the device a new URi or what? and how should i handle this?  Thanks

Comment: MPNS simply notifies of an URI change for a specific channel, that indeed is received by the device. It's up to you to take the appropriate action when that happens.

Comment: Ok got you, do you have some resource online to understand what should i expect from the server if this happened so as to know what to react to such an event?

Comment: One more thing, what if the channel uri was updated while the application is turned off, what happens then? The event won't be fired cz the application is turned of, right?  
If so , then how can i make sure that the URi the server has is alwaysup-to-date??

Comment: That's exactly the reason you should be checking for URI updates when the application is starting and binding to the channel. This document covers most of the theory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the annoyance, but i think i found the solution.  
One more thing and i'm done :), is this issue a timeout thing?? If so, what is the duration to expire? And if not then is it a random process where the MPNS changes the URi randomly?
Thanks